# Return a RTF String from Quill.js

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, quill

I want to get the simple RTF string from a Quill.js editor box that contains a formatted text.
My first approach was to convert the content to HTML and then to an RTF string, but that seems a bit of a hack, are there any better solutions to get the RTF string?

I want the plain RTF-String.